# DBContext constructor dependency injection returning null when inheriting an abstract class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dependencies, abstraction

I'm trying to create a database with translation tables for multiple languages and in order to have reusable components, I create abstract classes and interfaces for my entities. I am using dependency injection for `DBContext` in an abstract class that implements an interface.

This is the class that needs the DB Context DI:

```
public abstract class EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<TEntity, TTranslatableDetails, TTranslatedEntity> :
    IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<TEntity, TTranslatableDetails, TTranslatedEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityWithTranslatableDetails<TTranslatedEntity, TTranslatableDetails>
    where TTranslatableDetails : TranslatableDetailss
{

    public EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository()
    {
    }

    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public TTranslatedEntity Get(int id, string language)
    {
        var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        _context.Entry(entity).Collection(c => c.TranslatableDetails).Load();
        return entity.GetTranslatedEntity(language);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TTranslatedEntity> GetAll(string language)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Include(c => c.TranslatableDetails).ToList().Select(c => c.GetTranslatedEntity(language));
    }
}
```

Then I inherit the EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository

```
public class CarService : EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<Car, CarTranslatableDetails, GetCarDTO>{}
```

and then use DI again to inject it into a controller

```
public class CarController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<Car, CarTranslatableDetails, GetCarDTO> _carService;

    public CarController(IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<Car,CarTranslatableDetails,GetCarDTO> carService)
    {
        _carService = carService;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetACar")]
    public ActionResult<GetCarDTO> GetACar(int id, string language)
    {
        return Ok(_carService.Get(id, language));
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAllCars")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<GetCarDTO>> GetAllCars(string language)
    {
        return Ok(_carService.GetAll(language));
    }
}
```

The `DataContext` class looks like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

I register the DI in `Project.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<Car, CarTranslatableDetails, GetCarDTO>, CarService>();
```

When I run and try to get data I get the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

which points to:

```
var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
```

I have tried solving this problem by having the needed DI in the controller and passing `_context` to my functions as a parameter which worked. Is there a way to make my dependency injections work even in the abstract classes without needing to have them into the controller?

Comment: `IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository` should be registered as Scoped, exactly as `DbContext`, also remove constructor without parameters `EntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository()`

Comment: Hello Svytoslav, thank you very much for your comment, when I remove the parameterless constructor I get an error in my implementation class `CarService` which says: `There is no parameter that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context'`, and then I can add a base constructor to the `CarService` file, which removes the error but doesn't let me start the solution.